# Creating many arrays at once

Tags: python, arrays, os.walk

I am currently working with hundreds of files, all of which I want to read in and view as a numpy array. Right now I am using os.walk to pull all the files from a directory. I have a for loop that goes through the directory and will then create the array, but it is not stored anywhere. Is there a way to create arrays "on the go" or to somehow allocate a certain amount of memory for empty arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just append them to a list as you go:

```
lists = []

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(...):
    lists.append(...)
```

Comment: Each file is unique, however; and I don't want to put them all in a single array.

Comment: You can put lists inside of lists. So you will end up with a list that contains lists of filenames.

Answer (score 0):

Python's lists are dynamic, you can change their length on-the-fly, so just store them in a list. Or if you wanted to reference them by name instead of number, use a dictionary, whose size can also change on the fly.